# How to access nested objects in JSON using angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, pug

THis is the format of my JSON data:

```
[

 {

 "Department_id": "34",

 "Names": [

     "Jack Jones",

     "Matt Jones",

     "Lynn Lewis"

  ],

  "Employee-num": 3,

  "Salary-info": {

      "Jack Jones": 1000,

      "Matt Jones": 2920,

      "Lynn Lewis": 1500

    },

 },

]
```

How do you get the "salary-info"? And to display like the following:

```
Jack Jones: 1000

Matt Jones: 2920

Lynn Lewis: 1500
```

On jade, I try to access it using

```
p(ng-repeat='details in info.salary-info') {{ details }}
```

But it's not working and it only display a "0" on the screen.

**info.Department_id works for displaying the department id of 34.**

***Problem solved.***

The problem why nothing displayed is because of the hyphen exists on object names.

You need to access this kind of objects with a ' [" name of the object with a hyphen"] ',

like: {{ info["salary-info"] }}

instead of {{ info.salary-info }}.

Hopes it helps anyone having the same issue.

Comment: my guess is you could simplify api output for this ...`people:[{name:'Jack',salary:100]}`. Arrays can be sorted but objects can't. Also generally best not to use special characters in property names when it can be avoided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the hyphen in `Salary-info`.
For a demo, see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zeeyTbnsojY7s0dmE7GQ?p=info).

index.html

```
<!-- Jack Jones: 1000 Matt Jones: 2920 Lynn Lewis: 1500 -->
<p ng-repeat="name in details.Names">
  {{name}}: {{details['Salary-info'][name]}}
</p> <!-- works -->

or

<p ng-repeat="(name, salary) in details['Salary-info']">
  {{name}}: {{salary}}
</p> <!-- works-->

or

<p ng-repeat="(name, salary) in details2.SalaryInfo">
  {{name}}: {{salary}}
</p> <!-- works -->
```

all works, but

```
<p ng-repeat="(name, salary) in details.Salary-info">
  {{name}}: {{salary}}
</p> <!-- fails!-->
```

fails.

#### Data

app.js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.details =
      ...
        "Salary-info": {"Jack Jones": 1000, "Matt Jones": 2920, "Lynn Lewis": 1500},
      ...

  $scope.details2 =
      ...
      "SalaryInfo": {"Jack Jones": 1000, "Matt Jones": 2920, "Lynn Lewis": 1500},
      ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get keys and values from objects like so:

```
<span ng-repeat="(name, salary) in info['Salary-info']">{{name}} : {{salary}}</span>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties

Comment: <span ng-repeat="(name, salary) in  info["salary-info"] > {{name}} : {{salary}}</span>

Answer (score 2):

The `ngRepeat` syntax for objects is `(k, v) in obj` - so you can do:

```
p(ng-repeat='(name, salary) in info.salary-info') {{ name }} : {{salary}}
```

Comment: this syntax is working for "Names" since it is an array but I tried it for salary-info. It's not working.

Comment: @Brother_MW -- The above is object syntax - it won't work for arrays.

Comment: not sure will evalute `-` in property name using dot notation and also data has cap S  ... `info['Salary-info']` might be better